# Desenvolver para iPhone quando se é desenvolvedor Android

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, iphone

Desenvolvo para Android, agora estou querendo começar a desenvolver para iPhone, minhas dúvidas são as seguintes.

1. Utilizo Linux, pesquisando na internet conclui que a Apple só disponibiliza as ferramentas para Mac. E para programar em ambiente Linux e Windows só fazendo gambiarras. Alguém aqui conseguiu bons resultados desenvolvendo no Windwos ou no Linux?
2. A linguagem Objective-C e Java tem muitas semelhanças em relação a escrita?
   (EX.: sintaxe, heranças, implements, comunicação com BDs)
3. Qual um bom livro para iniciantes em desenvolvimento para iOS?

Comment: Esta pergunta tem tudo para vir a ser fechada por não ser objectiva - gera resposta baseadas em opiniões pessoais. Sugiro reformular a pergunta para: **É possível programar para iPhone no Linux? Como ?**

Comment: @ramaral, esta é uma dúvida comum entre desenvolvedores mobile, principalmente para aqueles que estão começando. O título sim poderia até ser melhorado, mas o conteúdo é de boa relevância. Abraços.

Comment: Acredito que algum moderador ja editou o titulo pois nao era esse "Desenvolver para iPhone quando se é desenvolvedor Android".

Comment: @JuarezA.FrancoJunior você pode conferir no [histórico de edições](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/37852/revisions) quem editou e o que foi mudado.

Comment: Para começar a aprender IOS eu assisti esses videos do link a seguir e li um livro Iphone e Ipad da noatec. Mais esses videos podem te ajudar no aprendizado. [Vídeos IOS](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuVwNXZzOwpnnxEADVlEOoQ)

Comment: Nao existe o pq editar o titulo para "É possível programar para iPhone no Linux? Como ?" Olha o conteudo da pergunta, estou com duvidas no novo ambiente de desenvolvimento, que inclui o sistema operacional, mas a duvida eh no ambiente de desenvolvimento, onde engloba o S.O, a linguagem, caracteristicas, diferencas entre o ambiente do android. Nao apenas no sistema operacional

Comment: Tirando o terceiro item, eu acho a pergunta boa sim. Dá para responder objetivamente os itens 1 e 2. O 3 é muito vago e atrai opiniões ao invés de fatos, além de ficar facilmente desatualizado.

Comment: Eu também acho a pergunta interessante. O meu comentário vem na sequência de haver já 3 votos para encerrar e, por uma questão de coerência comigo mesmo, eu também ter de votar para fechar. @Math Perguntas como ***Fica complicado?*** e ***É fácil?*** só podem gerar resposta baseadas em opiniões.

Comment: Oi, Juarez, tentei adaptar o título ao espírito da pergunta. Você é livre para mudá-lo como achar necessário. Desculpe se errei na interpretação. . . . Relacionado: [Baseado em opinião está sendo usada corretamente?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2072/201)

Comment: Acho incorreto suspender este tópico. Esta pergunta pode gerar respostas que ajudarão o programador a tomar suas próprias decisões.

Comment: @DanielAccorsi o fato de ajudar outros programadores a curto prazo pode significar atrapalhar a comunidade a longo prazo. Não estou dizendo que a pergunta deveria estar fechada, só estou dizendo que o motivo que você apresentou por si só não  sustenta uma reabertura do tópico (que a propósito, já ocorreu). Relacionado: [Por que não posso perguntar qualquer coisa sobre programação no StackOverflow Pt?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1947/3117)

Comment: Bom um fato que descobri e não vai ter jeito é que para programar para iOS é necessário um MacBook, não sou fan de gambiarras e muito menos fazer o software proprietário rodar ilegal, agora preciso saber como dar
um start, preciso de um livro ou apostila. Vou dar uma pesquisada na api do iOS e ver se ajuda um pouco. Mas o topico continua em aberto. Obrigado a todos que estao colaborando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amigo, coloco aqui minha observação sobre esta questão.

Existem duas forma de desenvolver aplicativos Android e iOS:

1º - Utilizando Frameworks. Neste caso você consegue compilar o mesmo projeto tanto para Android, como para iOS, veja um exemplo deste: [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) (que você desenvolve em C# para qualquer dispositivo móvel). Ou o [CoronaLabs](http://coronalabs.com/). Porém não recomendo esta solução, além de você ficar preso ao framework, você não terá toda flexibilidade que cada plataforma pode oferecer... Dentre outras questões, como desempenho e consumo de memória.

2º - Desenvolver de forma nativa. É a melhor opção e é o que as empresas mais respeitadas fazem: desenvolvedores Android e desenvolvedores iOS. A interface gráfica é disponibilizada igualmente para ambos, e no momento da implementação serão feitos os ajustes de acordo com a plataforma. Esta á a melhor forma de se trabalhar em projetos mobile.

Caso queria trabalhar de forma produtiva com iOS, recomendo fortemente não tentar gambiarras, e sim adquirir um Mac. Para Android, faça como você achar melhor dentro da flexibilidade da plataforma, ou seja, Linux ou Windows.

Falar sore semelhanças entre linguagens é complicado, mas o Objective-C tem muitas particularidades, assim como qualquer outra. Se você focar no aprendizado, conseguirá conhecimento tanto quanto Java. Mas sim, existe um mesmo conceito de POO para ambas, e é isso que importa.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma, conceitualmente.

Abraços.